# I want to train rvc model on colab, but error on "Load model Zip from Google Drive"

Tags: model, google-colaboratory

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jrsoiIQiJcbpgQPPFAHbbYo8-N88xIME?authuser=3#scrollTo=OVQoLQJXS7WX

this is link of file that Im using. I have train model, so I wanted to upload my model. but

these error messeage happened. how can I fix the error?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBzYZ.png)

I uploaded my model file to "unzip" file[enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX33Y.png)

and fixed file path-> MODELLOCATION: /content/unzip/Suisei.zip

but same error.
   `Archive:  /content/drive/MyDrive/Suisei.zip inflating: /content/unzips/Suisei/added_IVF3930_Flat_nprobe_1.index   inflating: /content/unzips/Suisei/Suisei.pth   no mv: cannot stat '/content/unzips/Suisei/*.npy': No such file or directory mv: cannot stat '/content/unzips/Suisei/Suiseino.pth': No such file or directory mv: cannot stat '/content/unzips/Suisei/Suisei.pth': No such file or directory mv: cannot stat '/content/unzips/Suisei/Suisei/*.index': No such file or directory mv: cannot stat '/content/unzips/Suisei/Suisei/*.npy': No such file or directory mv: cannot stat '/content/unzips/Suisei/Suisei/Suisei*.pth': No such file or directory`

how can I fix this error?